# wait for the response to get Procesed

Tags: bdd, cucumberjs, cypress

I am using Cypress.IO for the test automation and have struck with a scenario

These are my cucumber statements

Given I login in to SelfCare app using my user credentials
And I click on My Account

In the step definition of "I login in to SelfCare app using my user credentials" I am creating the subscriber and setting the local storage of the browser

To create a subscriber I need to call a Rest service and Process the response of he REST call and set the local storage

..............

And in the step definition of "I click on My Account" I am clicking a link

which we navigate me to dashboard page, to be successfully able to navigate the local storage must have few properties.
.....................

Cypress is not waiting for the first step to complete and navigating to second step which is causing a error

how to make cypress to wait for first step to complete ?

here is my source code

```
 Given(/^I login in to  app using my user credentials$/, () => {
    subscriberHelpers.createSubscriber();
});

Given(/^I click on My Account$/, () => {
    cy.log(window.localStorage.getItem('CD-SystemId'));
    cy.log(window.localStorage.getItem('CD-SessionId'));
    cy.log(window.localStorage.getItem('CD-SubscriberId'));
    //cy.get('.c-header-listItem > .c-link').contains("My Account").click();
});

export function createSubscriber() {

    cy.request({
        url: "Some URL",
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            "AutoLogin": true,
            "Credentials": {
                "Login": `AutomationUser${Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1000))}@sharklasers.com`,
                "Password": "Test1234"
            },
            "Subscriber": {
                "Category": 0,
                "Email": `AutomationUser${Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1000))}@sharklasers.com`,
                "FirstName": "Automation",
                "LastName": "Test",
                "Login": `AutomationUser${Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1000))}@sharklasers.com`,
            }
        },
        headers: {

        }
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200 && ("SessionId" in response.body))
            localStorage.write("CD-SessionId", response.body.SessionId);
            localStorage.write("CD-SubscriberId", response.body.Subscriber.Id);
    })
}
```

Comment: Is there an XHR request to get that data you could wait for?

Comment: The trick is to wait on some change to DOM that occurs after login. I don't think `cy.log()` has the built-in waiting that commands like `cy.get()` has. So, for example if a user name is displayed you could use `cy.get('.username').contains('AutomationUser123@sharklasers.com')` and this will wait (up to 5 seconds by default) for the string to appear.